# Cannot access PHP array with slashes in key

Tags: php, key, associative-array

I have an array that looks like this:
[image: items array]

For the life of me, I cannot access the array by key, for example, this does not work:

```
// $js is a string with value "lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"        
$key = "js/$js";
if (isset($items[$key]))
    $item = $items[$key];
```

This always returns false unless I specifically type in the key such as:

```
$item = $items["js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"];
```

Some times I just don't get PHP.

EDIT:
I dumped out the variables:

```
string 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' (length=32)
string 'js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' (length=35)
```

Comment: Then `$js` is not what you think it is.

Comment: try to echo $js and see if it really contains those indexes

Comment: Like the others say, it looks like `$js` isn't what you think... use a `var_dump($js); die();` to make 100% sure.

Comment: Am i do something wrong? http://pastebin.com/b83LgmuY It works fine.

Comment: $js is not what I think, there was an extra space at the end of the string! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there was an extra space at the end of the string... fixed by trimming the string:

```
$js = trim($js);
```